# Can't open WMS that worked before

Tags: qgis, wms, imagery

I've been trying to access a several WMS servers in order to visualize imagery on my QGIS but when I put the URL on the searcher no results are given, as if there were no WMS server with such URL . I've tried WMS URLs that have worked before, but I can't find them now. Nevertheless, those WMS servers with whom I had established connection prior this incident I haven't had any issues.

That's what I get after doing the search, basically nothing:

[image: QGIS dialog]

Any ideas?

Comment: Most likely there either is a temporary timeout of the service, or the server has been taken down for good.

Comment: http://geoservices.icgc.cat/icc_ortohistorica/wms/service?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities is still available

Comment: why not add again as a layer